# ImagePicker slow with large photos

Tags: performance, animation, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I apologize i don't have any code to show for this problem. But i hope i can explain it well enough.

What should happend.

Users Taps a Button:
  Image Picker is displayed. (present modal view)

User Chooses a photo:
the image picker dismisses (animated)
the chosen image is then loaded into a global object ( singleton)
and the chosen image is loaded into a IBOutlet UIImageView. in the current view.
A new view controller is pushed (animated ) which displays the image much larger.

For the most part this happens fine, however if a large photo, such as a photo taken by the iPhone 4 camera is loaded. the application lags and it jumps to the pushed view with no animations for the picker dismisal and the pushed viewcontroller.

is there a way to handle this better so the animations are shown?

performing certain task in the background with a selector?

Many thanks for your help.

Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only solution was to resize my image before pushing the next view controller!